VSCode discard changes gives fatal error 'is outside repository'
I'm working with a private GitHub repository that was cloned using VSCode.
When working on it, I realized that discarding changes wasn't working.
For instance, when I try to discard changes for the any file in the repo, I get this error:
> git checkout -q -- /Users/luiz/Códigos/GNSS PPP/batch_ppp/ppp_processor/ppp_batch_processor.py
fatal: /Users/luiz/Códigos/GNSS PPP/batch_ppp/ppp_processor/ppp_batch_processor.py: '/Users/luiz/Códigos/GNSS PPP/batch_ppp/ppp_processor/ppp_batch_processor.py' is outside repository at '/Users/luiz/Códigos/GNSS PPP/batch_ppp'

And this is the log:
2024-05-27 17:06:00.866 [info] > git checkout -q -- /Users/luiz/Códigos/GNSS PPP/batch_ppp/ppp_processor/ppp_batch_processor.py [7ms]
2024-05-27 17:06:00.866 [info] fatal: /Users/luiz/Códigos/GNSS PPP/batch_ppp/ppp_processor/ppp_batch_processor.py: '/Users/luiz/Códigos/GNSS PPP/batch_ppp/ppp_processor/ppp_batch_processor.py' is outside repository at '/Users/luiz/Códigos/GNSS PPP/batch_ppp'
2024-05-27 17:06:00.871 [info] > git config --get commit.template [4ms]
2024-05-27 17:06:00.873 [info] > git for-each-ref --format=%(refname)%00%(upstream:short)%00%(objectname)%00%(upstream:track)%00%(upstream:remotename)%00%(upstream:remoteref) --ignore-case refs/heads/main refs/remotes/main [6ms]
2024-05-27 17:06:00.878 [info] > git status -z -uall [4ms]

How can I solve this?

Please post the text of the error. You can format it as a quote. Reference: Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors? (but here the screenshot adds context so it's fine)

It'd also help to provide a translation of the buttons there. It seems like they're "Open the Git log", "Show the output of the command", and "Cancel'. Or even better, you could change the display language and post screenshots of that.

Have you looked at the output of the command and read the Git log? Hopefully you'd find useful details there

The error message seems perfectly clear. I would suggest listening to what it says.

I don't get it. Could you actually help? The file is in the repository in GitHub. I've cloned it with VSCode. I can commit changes without any problem, but I can't discard changes. Why?

@wjandrea, I've inserted the log but not different from the fatal error.

@lcoandrade Oh, that's a different error? This one is about a file in a subfolder, so maybe the subfolder is a submodule? But that wouldn't explain the first one, which wasn't in a subfolder... Sorry, thinking out loud.

Yeah, IDK what @matt's talking about either. The files are obviously in the folder, and the first screenshot showed that the file you were trying to revert was in M status, meaning it wasn't ignored, so I also don't know what the problem could be.

I did some research and found this: Computer Toucher's answer on "Why does git say that my file is outside the repository?", which talks about the Git setting precomposeunicode. That could be relevant since you have a non-ASCII character in the path to the repo.

@wjandrea, you were awesome! Thanks! It solved the problem!!!! Changing the name of my folder to Codes, solved the problem! Post your answer so I can upvote it.

@matt did not help at all! The file was already in the repo.

Looking at a related question, Why does git say that my file is outside the repository?, I saw an answer that talks about the Git setting precomposeunicode, which might be relevant since you have a non-ASCII character in the path to the repo.
It seems like you could either toggle this setting or rename that part of the path.
